# Executing a method on subclass in downcasting

Tags: java

How can I execute a method to generate data for subclass fields while down-casting the object?

For example:

```
public class Animal
{
  public string name;
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
  public string lastName;

//I want this method to be called when down casting...
  public void generateLastName()
  {
    this.lastName="Something";
  }
}
```

Comment: You can only downcast to your subclass if you have an instance of subclass with a superclass reference type. In that case all the subclass methods are accessible while downcasting. If you have an Animal reference type which is an instance of Animal, the subclass methods are not accessible.

Comment: Can you show an *usage* example that you are trying to make work? It's not clear what you are trying to do, but failing.

Comment: I have some objects from super class and I can't change the super class. and also I have some fields in the subclass that i want to be filled when i downcast the objects without calling the method by myself.

Comment: Your example does not seem to need downcasting.  Check the @Daniele for a polymorphism example.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to move lastname in superclass. Not well design to have superclass depends on child classes structure. You can set Animal as an abstract type and define as protected the overridable methods

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of this question,
I will pretend that downcasting is required and
that polymorphism is not a valid solution.

Use code similar to the following to downcast to a
`Dog` and access the `generateLastName` method:

```
public void someMethod(
    final Animal animalParameter)
{
    if (animalParameter instanceof Dog)
    {
        final Dog dogParameter = (Dog)animalParameter;

        System.out.println("Last name from animalParam: " +
            dogParameter.generateLastName());
    }
}
```

Options besides `instanceof` include the following:

1. `animalParameter.getClass() == Dog.class`
2. `animalParameter.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Dog.class)`
3. `Dog.class.isAssignableFrom(animalParameter.getClass()`

The difference between options 2 and 3 is "which class is a super class of the other".